# Electron APP packaging

Tags: electron

I'm trying to package my recent electron app. I tried to use electron-packager and I actually build the app though it is a bunch of files.

Now I'm facing some problems:

- How do I change the app icon? I did it by setting its path in BrowserWindow creation, but shouldn't I be able to do it with electron packager?
- And what about the actual desktop icon?
- And finally how should I do to package all the files built by electron-packager in one .exe?

I'm building it in windows for windows architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh i have faced that problem. first of all i'll leave you an example of how to use the API of `electron-packager`

```
 var packager = require('electron-packager');
var options = {
    'arch': 'ia32',
    'platform': 'win32',
    'dir': './',
    'app-copyright': 'Paulo Galdo',
    'app-version': '2.0.5',
    'asar': true,
    'icon': './app.ico',
    'name': 'TierraDesktop',
    'ignore': ['./releases', './.git'],
    'out': './releases',
    'overwrite': true,
    'prune': true,
    'version': '1.3.2',
    'version-string':{
      'CompanyName': 'Paulo Galdo',
      'FileDescription': 'Tierra de colores', /*This is what display windows on task manager, shortcut and process*/
      'OriginalFilename': 'TierraDesktop',
      'ProductName': 'Tierra de colores',
      'InternalName': 'TierraDesktop'
    }
};
packager(options, function done_callback(err, appPaths) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(appPaths);
});
```

Here i left you the link with all the information. [Electron packager API](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md)

And finally a module so you can build your installer easily, just follow their API.
[Windows installer](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer)

Comment: Hey thank you for the response. I already did what I want. But I did in a similar way. I built the app using electron packager API and than I built an .exe windows installer with inno setup

Comment: Hi, where to put this code? main renderer file or somewhere else?

Comment: @MohdShahid no, put it in another file, so you execute it with `node myfile.js`

Answer (score 1):

electron-builder is an all in one packager that will create a Windows installer (or other platforms) and allow you to set icons and many other settings. It actually uses electron-packager as a dependency for the actual packaging.

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder

Answer (score 1):

In Package.json

```
{
  "name": "APP_NAME",
  "version": "6.1.0",
  "description": "About APP",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm i -g electron-packager",
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-win32": "electron-packager ./ APP_NAME --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/YOUR_Icon.ico --out=release-builds --app-copyright=\"Copyright © COMPANY_NAME 2020\" --version-string.CompanyName=COMPANY_NAME"
  },
  "author": "YOUR NAME",
  "license": "YOUR LICENSE",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-packager": "^12.2.0"
  }
}
```